# capture outgoing packet sent by google chat in my application

Tags: java, android

I am familiar in using xmpp library,for android i'm using asmack library.In Google chat also asmack is used.i can write an application to send/receive messages using xmpp.But now i want to track google chat messages in my application.what ever the user do in google chat the same sholud be happening in my application.Suppose that user logged in google chat,in my appication also he is logged in.Sent messages /Incomming messages also should be in sync.i m able to do every thing except synchronizing outgoing sms.How to capture the packet when user is send a message from google chat into my application. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be able to do that (unless rooted) as it would be security issue - anyone could sniff your any network activity that way. If your app sign in to the google talk server (as any other client) then you should receive copies of all the conversations, but that's it.

Comment: so u mean, i can caputre incomming pack as iam connected to google chat server,but i cant get outgoing packet sent by google chat...are u sure...is there no way to do  ?

Comment: can u tel me the procedure if it is a rooted phone,how can i achieve it..?

Comment: I am saying that once you act as regular gTalk client, yours would receive all the conversation for given account even if it was made using other gTalk client than your. As for rooting - once you rooted your app can do mostly anything, bad or good, incl. network sniffing or re-routing it. It is not trivial if you never played with networking at that level however doable.